# Use Boost.Python to access C++ API for Teradata Parallel Transporter

Tags: python, c++, boost, teradata

Does Boost.Python have what it needs to wrap [C++ API for Teradata Parallel Transporter](https://downloads.teradata.com/sites/all/files/documentation/linked_docs/2516020A_TPT-API-Programmer-Guide.pdf) to enable transparent mapping (uploading and downloading data) between Python 2.7 Pandas DataFrames and Teradata Tables?

I have some experience with Python C (and Java - classes) but only have Python installed right now. So I'd like to avoid spending time installing all the dependencies just to find out that's not what I need.

Edit: rewritten the question in a closed form instead of asking for an opinion.

Comment: _"Is this a good idea ..."_ sounds pretty much asking for opinions (which is off-topic). At least list some pros and cons you have figured out yourself already.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question.